# Best way to get unique count of customers across multiple products

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

Using AWS Athena I am trying to write a query to get a count of the number of unique customers who have ordered per product.

If a customer ordered a product 5 times I only want them counted as 1 for the indicated product. Though I want them to be counted if they ordered 3 other products with different SKU codes. The issue is our product titles have changed over time and when I run the following query I get results by product title with the sku code listed out multiple times due to the change in product titles but want the unique customer count by sku_code.

```
SELECT product_title, product_code, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_reference_id)
FROM "business_usage"."daily_business_usage_by_instance_type"
GROUP BY product_title, product_code
ORDER BY Product_code
```

This is the query I have tried to get a distinct count for customers per sku purchased but get a Syntax_error:Unexpected parameters (varchar, varchar) for function count. Expected: count() , count(T) T for the first line

```
SELECT product_name, COUNT(DISTINCT sku_code, customer_id)
FROM "Data"."Orders"
GROUP BY product_name, sku_code
ORDER BY sku_code
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or if this is even the correct query to get the information I need?

Comment: Hi Brittanie. Have you tried to group by sku_code and customer_id? If product_name is a value that potentially can change over the time, maybe it's not a good idea to use it :). Please try it and comment the results. Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the number of unique customers by SKU, but you also want to retrieve the product title, which has changed over time and although related to SKU does not have a one-to-one relationship.

One way to achieve that is to group by SKU and use the [`ARBITRARY`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/aggregate.html#arbitrary) aggregate function to pick one product title from the group:

```
SELECT
  ARBITRARY(product_title) AS product_title,
  product_code,
  COUNT(DISTINCT customer_reference_id)
FROM "business_usage"."daily_business_usage_by_instance_type"
GROUP BY product_code
ORDER BY product_code
```

As the name suggest, [`ARBITRARY`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/aggregate.html#arbitrary) will give you a value, but it is not defined which, and it might vary from run to run. You could also use `MIN` or `MAX` to get the first and last in alphabetical order.

It could be the case that you want to pick a product title in a more specific way, like the one from the row with the highest timestamp. Assuming your table has a column called `order_date` you could use the [`MAX_BY`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/aggregate.html#max_by) function to pick the product title from the most recent row in the group:

```
SELECT
  MAX_BY(product_title, order_date) AS product_title,
  product_code,
  COUNT(DISTINCT customer_reference_id)
FROM "business_usage"."daily_business_usage_by_instance_type"
GROUP BY product_code
ORDER BY product_code
```